# Should I take care of n in memcmp?

Tags: c, memory

> The C library function int memcmp(const void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)) compares the first n bytes of memory area str1 and memory area str2.

should I get the min of strlen(str1) and strlen(str2)?

For example, I have a memory block pointed by `str1`, and a string `str2`, I want to compare `str1_len` bytes of `str1` memory block and `str2`

```
memcmp(str1, str2, str1_len); // suppose I already have str1_len
or
memcmp(str1, str2, str1_len < strlen(str2) ? str1_len : strlen(str2)); // should I compare first?

memcmp(str1, "ASDF", str1_len); // suppose I already have str1_len
or
memcmp(str1, "ASDF", 4); // is it safe to just use 4?
or
memcmp(str1, "ASDF", str1_len < 4 ? str1_len : 4); // should I compare first?
```

So my question is should I make sure `n` is less than the length to compare?

for example, if `str1_len` is 10, but `strlen(str2)` is 3, if I do a `memcmp(str1, str2, str1_len)` , is it safe?

or for example, say `str1` memory block is `18` bytes, and `str1_len` to compare is `10`, but I have a `str2` of `20` bytes, if I do a `memcmp(str1, str2, strlen(str2))`, is it safe?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use strcmp?

Comment: yes, str1 is not a string

Comment: Then why is it named `str1`? And what is it if it isn't a string?

Comment: It is a memory block pointed by str1, it is not null terminated

Comment: If it's not null terminated, then `strlen` is ill-advised.  You should know how many bytes are valid with each memory block you are comparing.  **What are you really trying to do?**

Comment: Thats why I use `str1_len` of `str1`, `str2` is a string

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, I have updated, hope its clear now

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. My best guess is that you want: `strncmp(str1, str2, str1_len);` (thanks @selbie)

Comment: @EvanBenn I have added two examples, hope it is clear now

Comment: If one of the blocks of memory are not 0-terminated, then you cannot relay on `strlen`. But of course in `memcmp` you would have to use the size of the smallest buffer, otherwise `memcmp` would read beyond the limits and you would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you, it clears my doubts.

Comment: With "I want to compare str1_len bytes of str1 memory block and str2", if `str_len > strlen(str2) + 1`, and all compares the same up `strlen(str2) + 1` , what functionality do you want?

Comment: Note: names have meaning.  Had this post used "I want to compare `size1` bytes of `mem1` memory block and _string_ `str2`", a lot less confusion would have occurred.

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is should I make sure n is less than the length to compare?

No, `n` *is* the length to compare. If you mean that you're considering setting `n` to the shorter of the two lengths, then that's fine, but you'll still need to handle the case where `str1` and `str2` have different lengths and the first `n` bytes are the equal. For example, `memcmp(str1, str2, n)` might return `0`, but then you still have to figure out whether `str1` or `str2` is longer than the other and act accordingly.

It sounds like you'd be better off using `strncmp()`, which works on strings but lets you specify a length. So you could call:

```
strncmp(str1, str2, str1_len)
```

in order to compare up to `str1_len` characters. Then the only extra case you have to consider is when that call returns `0`, indicating equality, but `strlen(str2)` is greater than `str1_len`.